# Why do I encounter RemoteCertificateNameMismatch every time?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

Consider the following complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RemoteCertNameMismatchDiagnosis
{
class Program
{
    private static bool AcceptAllCertificates(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
                                                                                        X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sslPolicyErrors.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient client;
        SslStream sslStream;

        bool acceptAnyCert = false;

        client = new TcpClient("google.com", 443);
        if (acceptAnyCert)
            sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertificates), null);
        else
            sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);

        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("test client");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

It reports this exception

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

every time. By changing `acceptAnyCert` to true on line 26, I can have it output this

> RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

, leading me to believe it's unhappy with the name on the cert.

This behavior persists whether I point at google.com, amazon.com, or anywhere else on line 28. I don't think google, microsoft, and amazon all have defective certificates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you browse to the urls yourself, with a normal browser, without certificate issues? What if you use an old browser? Could this be SNI serverside - unsupported in .NET?

Comment: To be clear here: .NET will send SNI on non-SSL2 handshakes on Windows Vista and later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass `"google.com"` to `AuthenticateAsClient` - it expects the server name as a parameter, not your client name.

Answer (score 0):

Just Updating my experience here, Recently, I got same issue in my SMTP communication with SSL enabled. Problem is - my client certificate name is not matching with server certificate and issue has been fixed by after changing my client certificate name as server certificate.

Regards

Abdul